# SQLPackage fail using synonyms into database project

Tags: sql-server-data-tools

I'm experiencing an issue during database deployment. I've several views that are using a function. Those views are not accessing the function directly but by using a synonym that then use the right function.

Are there any options in SQLPackage or in .NET Database Project to avoid this issue ?

When I apply the dacpac to an empty schema, using sqlpackage, the update fails because the view is created before the synonym of the function, this doesn't happen if inside the view I use the function directly.

I've a database project like the following one:

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpT5C.png)

Then I've created an empty Azure SQL Server database and tryed to publish to that database getting and error

[Publish Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cONQI.png)

saying "QNAVPLN_CALFASI_P, Line 7 Cannot find either column "DBO" or the user-defined function or aggregate "DBO.FN_CALENDAR_COLORS", or the name is ambiguous."

[Error detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTznS.png)

This error should not appear because both the function and synonym used are present in the database project.

Then I also tryed to remove the synonym and use directly the function (thing that should not be possible in our real project because of some other constraints) and everything works fine.

[Things are going right withouth synonyms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQGI8.png)

Thanks for your help

Comment: Try removing the "DBO." and leave out just function name. See if that works